# Trouble importing a png image with PIL

Tags: python, image, png

I want to import a png image but i'm unable to write imagetype as an argument for the Image function the correct way. I've tried writing "png", "PNG", imgtype="png" but it wont work. Does anybody know how to write this correctly. I'm using the code below. I'm using OSX btw.

```
from Tkinter import *
import PIL

root = Tk()
img = Image("this is where i'm supppsed to write imgtype", file="image.png")
panel = Canvas(root)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
panel.create_image(image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an image from *tkinters* `Image` class but it doesn't support `.png` images.

From the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm):

> The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:
>
> ```
> photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")
> ```
>
> If you need to work with other file formats, the Python Imaging
>   Library (PIL) contains classes that lets you load images in over 30
>   formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects:
>
> ```
> from PIL import Image, ImageTk
>
> image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
> photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
> ```

By doing `from Tkinter import *`, you are loading all modules from the `Tkinter` package into the global namespace, so `Image` in your case is actually `Tkinter.Image`.

To fix your issue, try:

```
pil_img = PIL.Image.open("image.png")
img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now i ran into a new problem however.. It says the _imaging C module is not installed

Comment: I found this article on effbot.org which may help: http://effbot.org/zone/pil-imaging-not-installed.htm